# How to enable proper work stealing in dask.distributed when using task restrictions / worker resources?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

**Context**

I'm using dask.distributed to parallelise computations across machines. I therefore have dask-workers running on the different machines which connect to a dask-scheduler, to which I can then submit my custom graphs to together with the required keys.

Due to network mount restrictions, my input data (and output storage) is only available to a subset of the machines ('i/o-hosts'). I tried to deal with this in two ways:

1. all tasks involved in i/o operations are restricted to i/o-hosts (they can run only on workers which run on machines that have access to the data) and non i/o tasks are restricted to non-i/o-hosts
2. all tasks involved in i/o operations are bound to workers providing the resource 'io' (the i/o-hosts) and non i/o tasks are bound to workers on non-i/o-hosts which provide the resource 'compute'.

The idea behind not allowing non i/o tasks to run on i/o-hosts is to make sure their workers are available for i/o tasks.

**Problem**

Both approaches work as expected in the sense that they restrict i/o-tasks to the right workers. However I noticed that when using any of the two approaches, only very few workers accumulate a lot of tasks while most other workers remain idle.

After reading up on how tasks are distributed among the workers I found that work stealing seems to be intentionally disabled for restricted tasks (http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/work-stealing.html). This seems to also apply for the resources framework.

**Question**

Is there a good way to combine restrictions on tasks with work stealing?

Comment: That's a good assessment of the situation and a fair point.  I recommend opening a GitHub issue to track it long term.

Comment: Thanks! I'll open a GitHub issue on the topic.

Comment: [Link to Github issue](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/1389)

Comment: And a merged PR here: https://github.com/dask/distributed/pull/3069. Work stealing with resources seems to work now (not yet tried myself)!