# dask.submit: Insufficent memory/load allocation in scheduler

Tags: memory-management, parallel-processing, dask, dask-distributed

Running a fine `dask` server:

[image]

Than I start pre-filling some data on the workers using `publish_dataset` and it looks the memory is pretty good allocated:

[image: running_dask_clister]

Next, I call `futures.append(client.submit(fn, values))` in a loop and afterwards `client.gather(futures)` - which works! But it is not as fast as assumed, because most of the **computation/memory load is beeing concentrated on 2 single processes** (worker4 and worker 1):

[image: bad_load_memory_allocation_dask_distributed]

Questions:

1. Why is Dask doing it like this?
2. Is it possible to *pre-load data on specific works* and than [`submit` to the specific workers](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/locality.html#user-control)?
3. Should I somehow re-allocate the used memory between the workers to enable better parallelization?

Related: [Dask Worker Stealing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46180830/how-to-enable-proper-work-stealing-in-dask-distributed-when-using-task-restricti) [Register Worker callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54449870/940592) and [Dask Actors per worker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54918699/940592)

Answer (score 0):

> Why is Dask doing it like this?

Unfortunately I don't know enough about your problem to know why Dask is choosing to do what it's doing.

> Is it possible to pre-load data on specific works and than submit to the specific workers?

Yes.  See the `workers=` keyword to `scatter` and `submit`

> Should I somehow re-allocate the used memory between the workers to enable better parallelization?

Dask should handle this for you.  I recommend using scatter rather than publish_dataset, which doesn't do what you think it does (I recommend looking through the docstring for each method)